# Issue with Mapstruct auto generated Mapper implementations

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, spring-boot, mapstruct

I am using Mapstruct for DTO to Entity and Vice Versa conversions. Everything is working fine, application is also running. But I don't know what's wrong with eclipse. After running mvn clean install I got a Mapper Implementation class in 'target/generated-sources' But it is through compile time errors. It is not able to find any of the classes in 'src/main/java'.

Can anyone suggest some solution?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting

```
<properties>
  <!-- automatically run annotation processors within the incremental compilation -->
  <m2e.apt.activation>jdt_apt</m2e.apt.activation>
</properties>
```

In your maven so Eclipse can have improved annotation processors.

Have a look at the [Eclipse](http://mapstruct.org/documentation/ide-support/#eclipse) section of the MapStruct website